# Haystack converting strings from Solr to ints

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I have a field in Solr that contains a registration number that usually follows the format:

```
"prop_33": "1923,1110.112"
```

The number of digits after the period is variable, but this isn't actually a float, the period is not supposed to represent a decimal point.

EDIT: The Solr field-type for "prop_33" is a `TextField`

I am using Haystack to query Solr, and when I call `SearchResult.get_additional_fields()` and then get the reg number from the resulting dictionary, it treats it as a tuple of an int and a float. If I call `str()` to convert it, it will round what it thinks is the second number and produce something nonsensical, like :

```
Museum Number (BM Registration Number ) : (1923, 1110.1120000000001).
```

Since this isn't actually a number, that makes no sense for my users. How can I get the exact string from the `SearchResult`, without it getting turned into a list of ints?

I'm still learning Haystack and Django, so I'm a bit new to all this.

EDIT: Here is where I am querying Solr:

_result_object.html - the template

```
<div id="collapsemed{{ obj.id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        {% get_result_details result.get_additional_fields %}
    </table>
</div>
```

base_tags.py - the template tags

```
@register.simple_tag    
def get_result_details(fields):
    rowhtml = ''

    for field, value in fields.items():
        if field.startswith('prop_'):
            prop_num = field[5:]
            try:
                prop = DescriptiveProperty.objects.get(id=prop_num)
                try:
                    row = '<tr><td>' + prop.property + '</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>'
                except TypeError:
                    row = '<tr><td>' + prop.property + '</td><td>' + str(value) + '</td></tr>'              
                rowhtml += row
            except DescriptiveProperty.DoesNotExist:
                pass

    return rowhtml
```

UPDATE: The problem seems to happen when Haystack returns a `SearchQuerySet` from the index. The reg number is correct in the index, but when I do the following from the console:

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> s = SearchQuerySet().filter(prop_31 = 116565)
>>> s.values('prop_33')
[{'prop_33': (1923, 1110.1659999999999)}]
```

Now it has become a tuple. Is there a way to tell Haystack to treat all values in the index as strings???

EVEN MORE UPDATE: I tried changing the type attribute of the prop_33 field in schema.xml from "text_en" to "string" and it made no difference.

Old Schema.XML:

```
<dynamicField name="prop_*" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

New Schema.XML:

```
<dynamicField name="prop_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Same result as before on the webpage and printed from the console.

Comment: What is the relevant field type in Solr that you have mapped the field to? Have you tried to check how the field is represented in the index? That will help you narrow down if the conversion happen before or after the data goes to Solr.

Comment: Yep @MatsLindh, the field-type is a TextField and in the index, the numbers look fine. Copying and pasting from the index, it appears as: "prop_33": "1923,1110.112" which is what I would like to appear when I query it from Django

Comment: What is the type of the field if you're just outputting it to the console when displaying it or something similar? Might be haystack or django trying to outsmart itself.

Comment: It does seem to be a problem with Haystack guessing the type when I create a SearchQuerySet(). Even tho the value is correct in the index, it turns into a tuple when I filter the SQS (see above).